# Microsoft NodeJS Zero to Hero: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson' and TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am taking a great course about NodeJS by Microsoft Virtual Academy; however, no one can seem to answer why I am getting these errors when running `app.js`:

```
    >node app.js
                                      Express server listening on port 3000
```

Then, I proceed to go to http://localhost:3000. Once I get there, the page loads, but immediately it breaks the connection and the output is as follows:

```
    GET / 200 10075.309 ms - 1122
    GET /js/index.js 200 28.290 ms - 329
    GET /css/bootstrap-theme.min.css 200 404.876 ms - 18864
    GET /js/bootstrap.min.js 200 406.395 ms - 31824
    GET /css/bootstrap.min.css 200 519.781 ms - 109522
    GET /css/style.css 200 427.435 ms - 204
    a user connected
    c:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Node.js Tutorials From Zero to Hero with Nodej\NodeMVA\NodeMVA\09_NodeChatroom\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\url_parser.js:14
      if(url.indexOf("mongodb://") != 0)
            ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
        at exports.parse (c:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Node.js Tutorials From Zero to Hero with Nodej\NodeMVA\NodeMVA\09_NodeChatroom\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\url_parser.js:14:9)
        at Function.MongoClient.connect (c:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Node.js Tutorials From Zero to Hero with Nodej\NodeMVA\NodeMVA\09_NodeChatroom\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\mongo_client.js:164:16)
        at Namespace.<anonymous> (c:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Node.js Tutorials From Zero to Hero with Nodej\NodeMVA\NodeMVA\09_NodeChatroom\app.js:47:11)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Namespace.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Namespace.emit (c:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Node.js Tutorials From Zero to Hero with Nodej\NodeMVA\NodeMVA\09_NodeChatroom\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:209:10)
at c:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Node.js Tutorials From Zero to Hero with Nodej\NodeMVA\NodeMVA\09_NodeChatroom\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:177:14
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Microsoft NodeJS Zero to Hero about 2 hrs 6 min in.

I am 2 hrs 6 min into it. They can run it okay, but I can't. I even reinatalled it from their github at https://github.com/sayar/NodeMVA. The folder is `09_NodeChatroom`.

I am running Windows 10
NodeJS v6.9.1

Here is the current package.json file dependancies:

```
    },
      "dependencies": {
        "bson": "^0.5.7",
        "express": "^3.4.4",
        "method-override": "^2.3.7",
        "mongodb": "^1.4.19",
        "pug": "*",
        "socket.io": "^1.0.6",
        "stylus": "^0.49.1"
      }
    }
```

I tried installing a later version of mongodb but that did nothing.

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i went on github and saw that the connection url for mongodb is process.env.CUSTOMCONNSTR_MONGOLAB_URI, you can find it on line 47 of app.js file.
Did you set that env var?

Comment: I was able to finally connect to the MongoDB database. Turns out that I needed to specify the location of the database (c:\data\storage.bson e.g.) Then the connection failed for another reason, which requires a different question since I still cannot figure it out.